# Kivy create new instance of widget

Tags: python, widget, instance, kivy

I'm fairly new to Kivy and have a few questions about widgets.
I started out messing with Kivy a few months back. I've read some documentation but I might have missed out lots of stuff.

Is it possible to create multiple instances of the same widget class with their own properties?

My goal is to have a few rectangles that I can resize and drag around independently.

I'm taking a java class so I'll compare to what I learnt in that class:
For example, lets say I have a basic rect.java class set up to take in two variables for width and height.

So in my main .java code file I would write something like this to create a few instances of the rectangle class:

```
rect s1 = new rect(2,3); // width & height
rect s2 = new rect(5,4);
```

Then, s1.height and s2.height will have different values.

Is it possible to achieve something similar in Kivy? For now I have many classes with the same properties set up in my .kv file:

```
<rect1>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 1, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.center_x - root.width/2,root.center_y - root.height/2
            size: self.size
<rect2>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 0, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.center_x - root.width/2,root.center_y - root.height/2
            size: self.size

<rect3>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.center_x - root.width/2,root.center_y - root.height/2
            size: self.size
```

I've written code in my .py file for it to be resized and dragged around. For now, I copied/modified the code to work with each additional class.

For now, if I use:

```
Window.add_widget(rect1)
```

It will create a new instance directly on top of the older one but they still share the same coordinates and other properties etc. If I drag with my mouse, all the instances of that class follow the same coordinates. Once again, my goal is to have multiple rectangles that I can resize and drag around independently.

Answer (score 1):

The `Window` should only have one widget (the application root widget). It's best to let this widget be added automatically by returning the root widget instance from `App.build()` or by including a root widget in your app's kv file.

In this case, a `FloatLayout` would make the most sense.

Also, you can use the `Scatter` widget to handle transformations - move (translate), resize and rotate - which might be easier than doing it yourself. Just wrap each widget in a `Scatter`, or make your widgets extend `Scatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Each entry you define with the angle brackets (<, >) are class declarations not instances. If you want to instantiate a class in the kv file with different properties then use the name without the angle brackets.

Here's some working code based on the code fragments you supplied:

```
<MovableRect>: 
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: root.color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<MyRoot@Widget>: 
    MovableRect: 
        id: rect1
        color: 1, 0, 1, 0.5
        pos: 5, 5

    MovableRect:
        id: rect2
        color: 1, 1, 0, 0.5
        pos: 130, 130

    MovableRect:
        id: rect3
        color: 0, 1, 0, 0.5
        pos: 250, 250    

# instantiation of root widget
MyRoot:
```

Here's the python file (without your movement functionality because you didn't list it):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class MovableRect(Widget):
    color = ListProperty([1, 0, 1, 0.5])

class Test1App(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test1App().run()
```

For a more complete example you can refer to the excellent kivy crash course series on youtube. There's one example that's very similar to what you're trying to do:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChmfVOu9aIc

Comment: how does one make make instances of widgets on the fly as, say, reacting to users input?